# How to search files in a specific folder and all its subfolders on Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, sharing, access-control

The reason I need to do this search is the need to remove sharing access for all files located in the specific directory (let's say "OLD" folder). I added folders with files there in a daily basis. I tried to remove access from the top: from the "OLD" folder, but it only removes access from the folder itself, not from the stuff in it. I can of course star the files which I move to the folder "OLD" and then to remove sharing access I can just search for is:starred, select all results and then remove access, but it is kind of inconvenient, as, e.g. I may sometimes forget to star the files before moving them to "OLD". I would prefer the easy way, even some link to bookmark, because I do that kind of access removal regularly (let's say weekly). If I can't find a way to do it, then I will go ahead to learn and write some Google Script to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The question was asked over [in the Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/vEPW91FtIP8).

There are some solutions but there is no formal way in the Google Drive web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Install Google File Stream. It'll put virtual copies of all your Drive files on your computer.

Then you can use your computer's search features to narrow searches to the folders you want to look in.

[Mac & PC versions here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7329379?hl=en)